# Mule:How to connect Mule ESB with Hybris?

Tags: mule, esb, mule-component, mule-el, sap-commerce-cloud

I have a requirement to connect Mule ESB with Hybris. I didnt find Hybris connector provided by Mule( Also didnt find sample examples as well).  This is the 1st time going to try Mule with Hybris..Please let me know the steps or efficient procedural way to connect Hybris.

Is the hybris URL enough to connect?. Please suggest me with your thoughts to implement. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hybris has many ways to integrate with their platform. If you have a login you can access their docs which details examples of integration with the platform including JMS and the Platform Web Services.

There is no connector supplied by Mule, but you can access their Platform Web Services which are implemented with a HTTP Restful API using the Mule http transport or by building your own connector using the Mule DevKit.

The hybris wiki has pages dedicated to most of the endpoints and the request/response formats. You can view this here if you have a login: https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/WebService+API+-+Reference

Also, in your hybris installation there are a bunch of examples in `/bin/ext-platform-optional/platformwebservices/src...`

and `/bin/ext-platform-optional/platformwebservices/testsrc` which show the actual web service implementations and their test cases using Jersey client.